# How to determine if a model uses soft deletes in Laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent, soft-delete

How do I determine if a model uses soft deletes in Laravel?

In [the Laravel API](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Database.Eloquent.Model.html/) I found the function isSoftDeleting(), but apparently that was removed from Laravel 4.2 now that it uses the SoftDeletingTrait.

How would I go about determining if a model uses soft deletes now?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to check programatically whether a Model uses soft deletes you can use the PHP function `class_uses` to determine if your model uses the `SoftDeletingTrait`

```
// You can use a string of the class name
$traits = class_uses('Model');
// Or you can pass an instance
$traits = class_uses($instanceOfModel);

if (in_array('SoftDeletingTrait', $traits))
{
    // Model uses soft deletes
}

// You could inline this a bit
if (in_array('SoftDeletingTrait', class_uses('Model')))
{
    // Model uses soft deletes
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you actually answered that at the same time I was writing my own answer. I'll mark yours as the answer since it's basically the same as mine. But I found when I used class_uses(), it returned an array with the entire namespace, not just SoftDeletingTrait, so that's what I had to look for: 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait'

Answer (score 3):

I needed to detect soft deletion on a model where the trait had been included in a parent class, so `class_uses()` did not work for me. Instead, I checked for the `bootSoftDeletingTrait()` method. Something along the lines of:

`// Class Name
$usesSoftDeletes = method_exists('User', 'bootSoftDeletingTrait');`

or

`// Model Instance
$usesSoftDeletes = method_exists($model, 'bootSoftDeletingTrait');`

should work.

Answer (score 2):

**For Laravel 5.x only**

If checking on main model:

```
//class_uses retrieves a list of traits from the object passed into an array
//Hence in_array check for name of trait (in string format)
//@param bool $usesSoftDeletes

$usesSoftDeletes = in_array('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes', class_uses($model));
```

If you are checking on the main model's relationship, use the following:

```
//Replace `myRelationshipName` by the name of the relationship you are checking on.
//getRelated() function fetches the class of the relationship.
//@param bool $relatedUsesSoftDeletes

$relatedModel = $model->myRelationshipName()->getRelated();
$relatedUsesSoftDeletes = in_array('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes', class_uses($relatedModel));
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured out out a good enough solution for my needs.

First I make this call:

```
$traits = class_uses($model);
```

Then I check for the the softdeletingtrait

```
$usesSoftDeletes = in_array('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait', $traits);
```

At least this way I avoid having to call the database for each model I test. Though it'll break if they change the SoftDeletingTrait name or location later on...

Answer (score 0):

There's basically not a direct approach on knowing if a model soft deletes by calling a function since the method `isSoftDeleting()` has been removed from 4.2. You know if a model is using soft delete if the `use SoftDeletingTrait;` is present in your Model's class and when the `deleted_at` column exists in your database table.

You can basically trust Laravel on removing a record from your database using soft delete when you have defined the `use SoftDeletingTrait` in your model's class, and have the `deleted_at` (is a TIMESTAMP) in your model's database table.

Comment: Thanks. I know I can check the database for that "deleted_at" column, but I was hoping to avoid that. My answer provides another solution.

Answer (score -1):

This is the best way

```
$model = 'App\\Models\\ModelName';

$uses_soft_delete = in_array('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes', class_uses($model));

if($uses_soft_delete) {
    // write code...
}
```

Comment: this doesnt have any improvement than existing answers