# How to check model use soft delete in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, model

i was made a model service trait to use with all models

some model use softDelete but some are not.

How i can check if model have softDeletes ability or not by checking if model contain column `deleted_at` or not

Here is my code to check

```
$isSoftDeleted = \Schema::hasColumn($model->getTable(), 'deleted_at');
```

is it a good way to do ?

Comment: The following answer could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25141187/755661

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way of checking (a little bit more raw) is checking for the existence of method `forceDelete`.

**METHOD 1 - Check if `forceDelete`** method exists

```
if(method_exists($model, 'forceDelete')){
    // Do your stuff here
}
```

Again, this is a little hack.

**METHOD 2 - Using an interface**

Generally is not optimal to check if a model uses a trait using `insanceof`, technically speaking it would be more appropriate to create an interface `UsesSoftDeletes` and make the model that actually use the `SoftDeletes` trait implement it. Doing that you could simply make a check using `instanceof` operator.

An example:

```
interface UsesSoftDeletes{
    //
}
```

then in your model

```
class User extends Model implements UsesSoftDeletes
{

    use SoftDeletes;

}
```

Then check with

```
if($model instanceof UsesSoftDeletes){
    // Do your stuff here
}
```

**EDIT - Checking for global scope**

You can also check if the model uses the `SoftDeletingScope` class (Laravel 5.x).

```
if($model->hasGlobalScope('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingScope')){
 // Do your stuff
}
```

Comment: `$model->hasGlobalScope('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingScope')` working for me, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `class_uses_recursive(static::class)` e.g.

```
$uses = class_uses_recursive(static::class);
return in_array(SoftDeletes::class, $uses);
```

Checking the column can only indicate that it exists, not that you're actually using the trait.

Note that `class_uses_recursive` is a Laravel helper function using the built-in `class_uses` but also ascending into parent classes.